# function in ejs with variable passed trought to HTML

Tags: javascript, function, ejs

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to make my page play a song on buttonclick.
The problem is that the song doesn't play and I'm not sure if everything gets passed through the right way.

What I do get in my console is that the page is trying to GET xxx.mp3 but that gives a 404.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title%></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    </head>

    <script>
        function playIt(song)
        {
            document.getElementById("embed").innerHTML="<audio src=\""+song+".mp3\" autoplay> <embed src=\""+song+".mp3\" hidden=\"true\" /> </audio>";
            return true;
        }
    </script>

    <body>

<% include templates/header.ejs %>
<h1><%= title%></h1>

<h3><%= muziek.Artist%> - <%= muziek.Album %></h3>

<div class="CSS_Table_Example" style="width:600px;height:720px;">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="20px"><h4>Nr</h4></td>
            <td width="110px"><h4>Title</h4></td>
            <td width="100px"><h4>Album</h4></td>
            <td width="100px"><h4>Artist</h4></td>
            <td width="100px"><h4>Length</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Play</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <% muziek.categories.forEach(function(item){ %>
            <td width="20px"><%= item.albumNumber %></td>
            <td width="150px"><%= item.title %></td>
            <td width="100px"><%= item.album %></td>
            <td width="100px"><%= item.artist %></td>
            <td width="100px"><%= item.length %></td>
            <td>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <button type="button" class="myButton" style="width: 250px" onclick="playIt(<%= item.albumNumber%>)">play <%= item.title%></button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="embed"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if i may use the `<script>` tags in ejs?
the songs are in the main folder and they are called 1.mp3, 2.mp3 and so on.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: If you get a 404, it means that your server cannot find the file (or isn't configured to know where to look for it). Can you include the code for your server as well?

Comment: Here is app.js : http://codeshare.io/VSg8p
Here is muziek.js : http://codeshare.io/uX9kD

Comment: the GET is this: "GET /1.mp3 404 4.396 ms - 1006"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is configured like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You state in your question:

> the songs are in the main folder

If by "main folder" you mean the folder where `app.js` is located, it is to be expected that the MP3 files can't be found, because you have told the static middleware to go look for them in a directory called `public/` (relative to the main folder).

Move the MP3 files to `public/` and try again.